Visual Proof of Harmonic Form Results
When you have $A\sin(x) + B\cos(x)$, I'm aware that is $\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}\sin(x+\arctan(b/a))$. I know how to prove this with algebra, but I was wondering if there was a visual proof to show this off.
I personally began by considering the case $3 \sin(x) + 4 \cos(x)$ to get my feet on the problem, getting an ellipse and considering "maximizing the sum of the coordinates on the edge of it". However, that became unfruitful quickly.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Am I over 30 characters (minimum answer size) yet?


Here's a non-overlapping variant of @SohamSaha's diagram (and a stylistic variant of a diagram shown in this ancient answer of mine):


$$\begin{align}
a\sin\theta+b\cos\theta &= c \sin(\theta+\phi) \\[4pt]
a\cos\theta-b\sin\theta &= c \cos(\theta+\phi) 
\end{align}$$
$$a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \qquad \tan\phi = \frac{b}{a}$$
